# Spree Mail Method is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

In spree admin panel under configuration menu, I configured mail smtp, port and etc., after creating new mail method I press test mail button, I got following alert message "Testmail sent successfully" and even terminal window also display email send successfully message but the mail is not delivered to the corresponding address

**Console log after sending test mail**

```
Sent mail to abc@xyz.com (5ms)
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2013 03:11:43 -0700
From: test@spree.com
To: abc@xyz.com
Message-ID: <************************>
Subject: [["message"]] Spree Demo Site Testmail
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Congratulations!
================

If you have received this email, then your email settings are correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that

Mail delivery in Spree is disabled by default. You can enable it in two ways.

First, if you need to keep your default Rails app action mailer configs you need to tell Spree to not override them by setting the `override_actionmailer_config` option to `false`.

You should also tell Spree which email should go on the header from using the `mails_from` option. A typical spree initializer which disables all Spree default mail settings and interceptor looks like this:

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.override_actionmailer_config = true  
  config.mails_from = "no-reply@yourdomain.com"
end
```

refer [**`spree mail delivery`**](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deployment_tips.html)

Please let me know

Comment: Thanks, I could not see this line in config/environments or config/application.rb file

Comment: @RajarshiDas can you help me to set up the _Spree Email_ configurations ?

Comment: For anyone visiting in 2019, mails_from does not exist anymore. (P.S. spree_mail_settings gem is therefore broken)