# How to Send Email in Development with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, spree

I'm in the development environment and I want to send out test emails via my console. I got the console going nice, but its not sending.

I go to Spree's Mail Method Settings and here's what I got:

[image: Spree Mail Method Settings for BenMorganIO]

I've double checked the password. I've Googled the hell out of it. I can't figure out how to get this thing to work.

Key Question: How does one get email working in Spree from the development environment?

**Things I Tried**: [Spree Mail Method is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063241/spree-mail-method-is-not-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you need a local email server that can receive your emails.  To test the setup in development install the mailcatcher gem, that you will use as a SMTP server in development, catching all incoming mails and displaying them on `http://localhost:1080/:`

Just run in the terminal

> gem install mailcatcher

then run `mailcatcher` in the console. A toy SMTP server will be running on port 1025 catching emails and displaing them on HTTP port 1080.

Then just goto the spree admin panel and configure it. The following settings work perfectly for me without any code writing.

[image]

After I clicked on `send test mail` I got the following email on my localhost:

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway that I can see the HMTL version?

Comment: You could open the email and "view source" of the webpage. But this is just a hunch. You could check out the mailcatcher webpage for more

Answer (score 4):

Spree actually overrides the ActionMailer settings with the settings input in the graphical interface using the Spree::MailMethod class.  On the plus side, you can set things in the admin interface, with a downside of several unexpected behaviours.

We maintain many Spree stores and we always run with the settings:

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.override_actionmailer_config = false
  config.mails_from = "no-reply@yourdomain.com"
end
```

This will allow you to configure ActionMailer as you would in any other Rails application:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration

This is being adopted as standard procedure for the next release of Spree after 2.2.x.

https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/4377 has extracted the web configuration to its own gem to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: Or just use this bad boy: https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings :D

Comment: I just like that "send testmail" button tbh. Other than that, this is the way to go.

Comment: Got the file `config/initializers/spree.rb`.

Comment: @gmacdougall : I got this error `/preferences/configuration.rb:66:in `method_missing': undefined method `override_actionmailer_config=' for #<Spree::AppConfiguration:0xbe2d5dc> (NoMethodError)` what I do wrong?

Comment: You do not need to specify this option in newer versions of Spree. It is now the default.

Answer (score 0):

Spree commerce use ActionMailer to send emails. If you want send emails in development mode, you should enable `delivery_method` in `config/enviranments/development.rb` file.

Just set this variable `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises because you don’t have a local email server to receive your emails.

**Step 1:** 
The first step would be to Install the mailcatcher gem in order to test the setup in development.

You will be using it as a SMTP server to catch all the incoming mails and display them on http://localhost:1080/:

**Step 2:**
Just run in the terminal “**gem install mailcatcher**” in the console.

You will find an SMTP server running on port 1025 catching emails and displaying them on HTTP port 1080

**Step 3:**
You will find an SMTP server running on port 1025 catching emails and displaying them on HTTP port 1080

**Add line:**
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: 'master‘

**Then run:**
bundle

**Step 4:**
Further, go to “Spree admin panel” and configure it. These settings will work perfectly for you without any code writing.

Then click on “**Send test mail**”

**Step 5:**

You will receive the an email on your local host.

Now your problem is solved.