# Mailcatcher not working with Spree and Vagrant

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, vagrant, spree, mailcatcher

I am currently using Spree 1-3-stable and trying to use Mailcatcher to catch all test emails sent in a development environment. I am also running the project in a Ubuntu virtual machine using Vagrant (w/ VirtualBox). When I run Mailcatcher, the web interface properly displays on port 1080, but it doesn't capture any emails when I send test emails via the Spree Admin panel. I followed the instructions of the selected answer here already: [How to Send Email in Development with Spree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648252/how-to-send-email-in-development-with-spree). The emails show up in the server log, but not in mailcatcher's web interface. I have the exact same setup in the Spree Admin Mail Method Settings. SMTP Mail Host is localhost and SMTP Port is 1025.

Because I'm using Vagrant, I also followed this discussion here https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/89. I already added port forwarding in my Vagrantfile:
`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 1080, guest: 1080`

I also ran mailcatcher --http-ip=0.0.0.0 instead of just mailcatcher.

So far, this hasn't been working for me. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have config.override_actionmailer_config = false somewhere in your Spree initializer?

Comment: @gmacdougall I do not. Should I?

Comment: Yes. If you're trying to configure things through ActionMailer (which mailcatcher probably hooks in to) you should avoid the Spree indirection around mail settings. This was removed in a recent version of Spree due to issues like the one you're experiencing.