# ActionMailer not sending mail in development using Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, spree

I'm using Spree to develop an E-commerce. I was using part [this](https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails) tutorial to send emails using ActionMailer, but I can't make it work.

**My controller**

```
 UserMailer.sign_up_confirmation(spree_current_user).deliver
```

**My develpment.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      user_name: ENV['gmail_username'],
      password: ENV['gmail_password'],
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

There is no error in the console and the mail it seems to be delivered right, but there is no email on my gmail account. I used this code in a previous project and worked fine. So, is Spree doing something to my email delivering?

Comment: have you tried `deliver_now` instead of `deliver`?

Comment: @Cyzanfar yes, and is not working.

Comment: does this post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648252/how-to-send-email-in-development-with-spree